# Unable to upload a file tried using sendkeys?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to upload a file from my maven project but I am  unable to upload in any way: How do I upload a file from my project?

```
      <input data-ng-controller="uploadControl" type="file" title="Browse 
      and select a file to upload." name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" ng- 
      disabled="isURLActivity" class="ng-scope" data-role="upload" 
        autocomplete="off">
        <span>Browse...</span>
```

Locator of the element:

```
      @FindBy(xpath = "//div[(text() = 'Browse...' or . = 'Browse...')]")
      public WebElement browse;
```

1st way which I tried:

```
     WebElement browse= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[(text() = ' 
     'Browse...' or . = 'Browse...')]"));
     browse.sendKeys("Path of file");
```

And 2nd way which I have tried:

```
    Actions actions= new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(browse).build().perform();
    actions.sendKeys(browse,"Path of file").build().perform();
```

Actual Result:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not 
>   interactable    (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)  Build info:
>   version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-
>   11-06T11:42:16'

Comment: can you share url for same? and is it inside frame?

Comment: File was getting uploaded through robot class but not through sendkeys..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using either [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) or [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) classes as they might cause a lot of problems when it comes to [Parallel Test Execution using i.e. Selenium Grid](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices) or other multi-threaded approach.

Your problem is that you're using the wrong element. It seems that you're trying to send keys to [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) tag and you should be rather using the [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

So change your code to look like:

```
@FindBy(id= "fileUpload")
```

and everything should start working as expected.

Just in case you prefer XPath:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@title, 'Browse')]")
```